# Combined: Mouse down, mouse move and button click

Tags: button, mousemove, mousedown

I'm using c# wpf. What i want to do is,

**A button:**  When the user clicks the button, rectangular selection is enabled. Then user can draw rectangle on panel.

**Mouse down event:**  When the user clicks the mouse button , it gets the x axis of the current position on panel.

**Mouse move event:** After clickling , if the user moves the mouse to the left my code1 is going to run. If the user moves the mouse to the right my code2 is going to run.

*Code1:*
When the user moves the mouse to the right after clicking on panel user is going to draw green rectangle and when user releases the mouse button that rectangle disappears and selects the objects in the rectangle.

*Code2:*
When the user moves the mouse to the left after clicking on panel user is going to draw red rectangle and when user relases the mouse button the rectangle disappears and selecte the objects in the rectangle and the objects that rectangle intersects.

Here is what i got:

```
public static System.Drawing.Point mouseLocation2;

public static System.Drawing.Point posmousedoWN;
```

***Button Click Event:***

```
private void btnSelectBox_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)    
    {
        if (btnSelectBox.IsChecked.Value)
        {

            if (mypartialclass.mouseLocation2.X > mypartialclass.posmousedoWN.X)
            {
                //code1
            }

            if (mypartialclass.mouseLocation2.X < mypartialclass.posmousedoWN.X)
            {
                //code2
            }
          }  
        }
```

***Mouse Down event:***   (This event is in mypartial class)

```
protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e)         
    {

        posmousedoWN =  RenderContextUtility.ConvertPoint(e.GetPosition(this));     
}
```

***Mouse Move event:***   (This event is in mypartial class)

```
protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)          
    {

        mouseLocation2 = RenderContextUtility.ConvertPoint(e.GetPosition(this));
}
```

This code is not working. When i click the button first code1 runs. Then always code2 runs. What am i missing?